# How to merge asynchronous function's callback result

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

Here is the code to get some information about server.

```
    cpu.usage()
    .then(info => {
        console.log(info);
    });

    cpu.free()
    .then(info => {
        console.log(info)
    });

    mem.info()
    .then(info => {
        console.log(info)
    });
```

I want to get every result in a function.

```
get_resource () {
   ...
   console.log(cpu_usage, cpu_free, mem_info);
};
```

How can I design it?

Thank you.

Comment: `Promise.all()`

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use `async/await` to do that:

```
var get_resource = async function () {
   var cpu_usage = await cpu.usage();
   var cpu_free = await cpu.free();
   var mem_info = await mem.info();

   console.log(cpu_usage, cpu_free, mem_info);
};
```

Or

```
Promise.all([cpu.usage(), cpu.free(), mem.info()]).then(function (info) {
    console.log('cpu_usage:', info[0]);
    console.log('cpu_free:', info[1]);
    console.log('mem_info:', info[2]);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) as following:

```
let cpuUsage = cpu.usage()
let cpuFree = cpu.free()
let memInfo = mem.info()

Promise.all([cpuUsage, cpuFree, memInfo]).then((values) => {
  console.log(values);
});
```

If you can use ES6, then you can use array destructuring while getting results:

```
Promise.all([cpuUsage, cpuFree, memInfo]).then(([cpuUsageResult, cpuFreeResult, memInfoResult]) => {
  console.log(cpuUsageResult);
  console.log(cpuFreeResult);
  console.log(memInfoResult);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

## Callback Hell

This is the old scenario where you would have to call things inside one another

```
    cpu.usage()
    .then(cpu_usage => {
      cpu.free()
      .then(cpu_free => {
        mem.info()
        .then(mem_info => {
          console.log(cpu_usage, cpu_free, mem_info);
        });
      });
    });
```

## Async Await

in this scenario you make a function that is asynchronous.

```
async function get_resource () {
    const cpu_usage = await cpu.usage();
    const cpu_free = await cpu.free();
    const mem_info = await mem.info();
   console.log(cpu_usage, cpu_free, mem_info);
};
```

The value assigned to each `const` in the async function is the same value that you get as an argument in the callback of the `then`.

Comment: It looks so cool. thank you. I tried Callback hell way before the question. Now I know the exact way to use Async Await via your example.